# split and publish string with delimiters

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I using using rails and have a variable from the dataset that has multiple string entries separated by semicolon.  I'd like to publish these in a table and would also like to ignore instances where they are blank.

My database might look like this:

```
state: TX;PA;NJ;NY
```

I'd like to publish these in a table so it looks as follows:

[image]

My model is adviser and the attribute is state.

```
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>State</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><%= adviser.state %></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I tried using `split` function, but am not having any success.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are `;` separated or `,` separated `TX;PA;NJ,NY`?

Comment: they are separated by `;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `#split` method for that. Something like:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <% adviser.state.split(';').each do |state| %>
      <% next if state.blank? %>
      <td><%= state %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Glad to know that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` by passing `;` and reject the blank ones, like:

```
<% adviser.state.split(';').reject(&:blank?).each do |stat| %>
  <%= stat %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thanks @sebastian, i'm getting `undefined method each for nil:NilClass` error.  I know `adviser` is valid, cause I can list attributes without using the `split` function.

Comment: `reject!` will return `nil` if there's no blank value in the array. For instance, `['test'].reject!(&:blank?)` will return `nil` and `nil.each` will give `undefined method each for nil:NilClass` error. You can use `reject` instead.

Comment: Yes but `"TX;PA;NJ;NY; ;".split(';')` will. `# => ["TX", "PA", "NJ", "NY", " "]`